# Bootstrapping t-statistics order of approximation error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, bootstrap, asymptotics

Consider bootstrapping the $t$-statistics: $T_n = T(X_1,...,X_n) = \sqrt{n-1}\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\hat{\sigma}}$ for iid observations $(X_1,...X_n)$, where $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X})^2$..

Now, I know from the Central Limit Theorem that $P(T_n \leq x) \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{} \Phi(x)$, for $\Phi(x)$ the standard normal cdf.

For each bootstrap resample, suppose instead of making $n$ iid draws with replacement from the empirical distribution, I only make $m = n/2$ iid draws with replacement from the empirical distribution.

I am wondering what the order of the bootstrap approximation error is in terms of $n$ (e.g. $O(n^{-2})$) for the following: $| P(T_n \leq x \mid F_0) - P(T_n^* \leq x \mid F_1)|$.

Maybe my notation is unclear, but I denote the bootstrap version of $T_n$, by $T_n^{*}$, and it is given by $T_n^{*} = T(X_1^*,...,X_m^*) = \sqrt{m-1}\frac{\bar{X}^* - \bar{X}}{\hat{\sigma}^*}$, where $(X_1^*,...,X_m^*)$ are $m = n/2$ iid draws from the empirical distribution, $F_1$, which places probability $\frac{1}{n}$ on each of the observations $X_1,...X_n$. Let $\bar{X}^* = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_i^*$, and additionally let $\hat{\sigma}^{*2} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(X_i^* - \bar{X}^*)^2$.

Can someone help me understand how I can figure out the order of approximation error for the above? $| P(T_n \leq x \mid F_0) - P(T_n^* \leq x \mid F_1)|$. Similarly, how would this compare to $| P(T_n \leq x \mid F_0) - \Phi(x)|$? My thoughts are that the edgeworth expansion would be somewhat helpful here. My thinking is that the convergence rate does not change and neither does the error.

Comment: In your second paragraph you say "*Now, I know from the Central Limit Theorem that*" ... You would need more than the CLT for that, since the CLT doesn't use sample standard deviations. Slutsky's theorem should suffice to plug that gap, I think.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, it would be verified with Slutsky's theorem I agree. Also, the edgeworth expansion would make it more clear.